# Validate and reset system clock on ASP.NET website startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, virtual-machine

I have an ASP.NET application that is hosted on a farm of virtual servers with time problems.  The symptoms are that when servers startup or reboot they often come up with a bad system time (potentially hours off).

(Obviously the best answer would be to solve the system problem, but that is currently beyond my control...)

So here's the question:  Is there are straight forward way for me to get my ASP.NET application to query an authoritative NTP server on startup and then reset the system clock if needed?

Technical assumptions:
* ASP.NET 4.0
* Windows 2008
* Full local admin rights on server

Comment: I don't think the application is the right place to be doing that. I think there are tools available to keep times synced. Windows Time Service maybe?

Comment: Totally agree that is the "right" way to deal with it.  I'm just trying to come up with a work around on a poorly administered environment...

Comment: Keep in mind that there may be weird behaviors due to changing the system clock while an ASP.NET application is running.  For example, changing the clock can inadvertently cause the application pool recycling timeout to be hit, which will bring down your w3wp.exe process.  Use caution.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this using [WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Though I don't have personal experience with doing so, there are numerous examples out there. To start:

1. The classes in [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145024.aspx) will help you query WMI from within the .NET framework
2. MSDN example: [connecting to a remote computer to run a WMI query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257337%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
3. WMI scripts: [Date/Time tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
4. [The Win32_LocalTime class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
5. Using the [WMI Update Query Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393945%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to update system information

Hope that sets you off in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the application is the right place to be resetting system time. If I'm not mistaken, Windows Time Service can manage this:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/configuring-windows-time-service.html

Comment: The problem is that evil forces beyond my control are configuring the server and launching my application on it.  My first point of contact is on application startup...  I could just have the app fail if the clock is too far out of whack, but I would "like" to be able to "automagically" fix the problem without firing up an RDP session to the server...

Comment: That's a tough one... can you create a service to run on the servers?